# Android: trying to build custom adapter for gallery view and add images to it dynamically at runtime

Tags: android, gallery, adapter

I am trying to use a gallery view to display the pictures a user selects. I built a custom adapter from BaseAdapeter (see below) to store  custom 'Pic' objects that each store a bitmap and a path for the image. When a the activity is started the adapter is created without any Pics and as the user selects an image I am adding a Pic to the adapter and resetting the adapter to the gallery (see below). What actually happens is nothing. No errors or anything but the gallery doesn't update and display an image when a Pic is added to the adapter and the reset. I will post the adapter code in entirety and the method where I add a Pic and reset the adapter. Any help would be appreciated, or if I am going about this wrong please direct me appropriately. Thanks in advance.

The GalleryImageAdapter I created:

```
public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Serializable {

private Context mContext;

private List<Pic> pictures;

public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context) 
{
    mContext = context;
    pictures = new ArrayList<Pic>();
}

public void addPicture(Pic p){
    pictures.add(p);
}

public void removePicture(Pic p){
    pictures.remove(p);
}

public int getCount() {
    return pictures.size();
}

public List<Pic> getAll(){
    return pictures;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (pictures.size() > position){
        return pictures.get(position);
    }
    else{
        return position;
    }
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


// Override this method according to your need
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    i.setImageBitmap(pictures.get(index).getImage());
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));

    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    return i;
}
}
```

The method that is supposed to update the gallery:

```
private void AddNewAfterSelection(Pic pic){
    giAdapter.addPicture(pic);
    gallery1.setAdapter(giAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gallery is deprecated, you should think about using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) or [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).  There's a good example of ViewPager at the link above that uses an adapter.  For HorizontalScrollView, you can simply inflate your views and call horiztonalscrollview.addView(View yourView) to add things at runtime.